# Get data from Sql tables using Entity Framework in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use VS 2015 and Entity Framework 6.2.0.
I have two tables `tblUsers` and `tblFields` in sqlServer.
I create two models related to my tables:

```
[Table("tblUsers")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDateTime { get; set; }
    public string FieldId { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblFields")]
public class Fields
{
    [Key]
    public string FieldID { get; set; }
    public string FieldTitle { get; set; }
}
```

So, in my DataAccessLayer, I have:

```
public class Dal : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().ToTable("tblUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fields>().ToTable("tblFields");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Users> UsersSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fields> FieldsSet { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the following code in BusinessLayer to get Users Data:

```
public List<Users> GetAllUsers()
{
    Dal dal = new Dal();
    return dal.UsersSet.ToList();
}
```

No users are return!
Where is the problem?

Comment: your entities seem to be fine. Maybe the problem is located in the insert of your data.. Have you checked the database to actually see if any data are in this table?

Comment: Yes, table has 5 rows data.

Comment: was thet table created by entity framework or are you just trying to map it?

Comment: I created the tables in sqlServer and now want to use them.

Comment: Wow! I deleted all tables from datatbase. Then I ran the application. Application created all tables again and problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I create a database and it's tables. Then I created my project that used from database. The problem is here!

Solution: I deleted all tables from database and then I run my application. Application created all tables again and problem is solved.